# How to explicitly set value for a model in MVC partial view

Tags: c#, ajax, json, model-view-controller, submit

I have a model in a Partial view(Ajax.BeginForm) that has few properties. Some of them get set by the user but there is one that I always want to be set to true explicitly. How can I do that? here is my Code:

@model Path.To.MyModels.BlanksVM

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BodyMassIndex"
                        ,"Blanks"
                        , FormMethod.Get
                        , new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "FillUpFields" }))
          {
            <table style="margin: 0px auto; margin-top: 10px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Weight: </span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>  m.FieldValues["bodyWeight"])
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>Height: </span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FieldValues["bodyHeight"])
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>IBM: </span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FieldValues["indexOfBodyMass"])
                        </td>                 
                </tbody>          
            </table>

            <div style="padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate" style="padding: 3px;"/>
            </div>
         }
```

Inside of the **BlanksVM** model I have a property called "**MakeCalculations**" and I am trying to always set it to true after submission. Can you help me do that?

Comment: Since it's always true, you can just set it to true in side the action result that your ajax form point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MakeCalculations, new { @Value = "true" })
```

If you have to do it in the form.

But that is probably not the best way.. if it's always true then why do you need to set it?